# How to capture still image and save with its city name with AV Foundation camera?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-location

I capture still image and save to camera roll with AV Foundation like this:

```
- (void) captureStillImage
{
    AVCaptureConnection *stillImageConnection =
    [self.stillImageOutput.connections objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([stillImageConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
        [stillImageConnection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];

    [self.stillImageOutput
     captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:stillImageConnection
     completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
     {
         if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL)
         {
             NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput
                                  jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
             ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
             UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
             [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage]
                                       orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation]
                                   completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
              }];
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Error capturing still image: %@", error);
         }
     }
     ];
}
```

These images from my App when check again in Photos App don't have info about city name.

How to capture still image and save with its location name which can be display in photos app?

Thanks for help!

Comment: See this..it may help you..http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Docs : [captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureStillImageOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureStillImageOutput/captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection%3acompletionHandler%3a)

> handler
>
> A block to invoke after the image has been captured. The block
>   parameters are as follows: imageDataSampleBuffer The data that was
>   captured. The buffer attachments may contain metadata appropriate to
>   the image data format. For example, a buffer containing JPEG data may
>   carry a kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary as an attachment. See
>   ImageIO/CGImageProperties.h for a list of keys and value types.

So using that you can get the meta data.

```
         CFDictionaryRef metaDict = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(NULL, imageDataSampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
         CFMutableDictionaryRef mutable = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 0, metaDict);


         NSDictionary *metaDict = [NSDictionary
                                  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude], kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude,
                                  @"N", kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitudeRef,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude], kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude,
                                  @"E", kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitudeRef,
                                  @"04:30:51.71", kCGImagePropertyGPSTimeStamp,
                                  nil];
         NSLog(@"%@",metaDict);
         CFDictionarySetValue(mutable, kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary, (__bridge const void *)(metaDict));
```

and when saving to Asset Library use this method to add the meta data

```
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] metadata:mutable completionBlock: nil];
```